# Display content by category

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

There are such buttons in the navbar, how to do this - when a tab is selected for the specified content for this category

```js
// ---------Responsive-navbar-active-animation-----------
function test(){
    var tabsNewAnim = $('#navbarSupportedContent');
    var selectorNewAnim = $('#navbarSupportedContent').find('li').length;
    var activeItemNewAnim = tabsNewAnim.find('.active');
    var activeWidthNewAnimHeight = activeItemNewAnim.innerHeight();
    var activeWidthNewAnimWidth = activeItemNewAnim.innerWidth();
    var itemPosNewAnimTop = activeItemNewAnim.position();
    var itemPosNewAnimLeft = activeItemNewAnim.position();
    $(".hori-selector").css({
        "top":itemPosNewAnimTop.top + "px", 
        "left":itemPosNewAnimLeft.left + "px",
        "height": activeWidthNewAnimHeight + "px",
        "width": activeWidthNewAnimWidth + "px"
    });
    $("#navbarSupportedContent").on("click","li",function(e){
        $('#navbarSupportedContent ul li').removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass('active');
        var activeWidthNewAnimHeight = $(this).innerHeight();
        var activeWidthNewAnimWidth = $(this).innerWidth();
        var itemPosNewAnimTop = $(this).position();
        var itemPosNewAnimLeft = $(this).position();
        $(".hori-selector").css({
            "top":itemPosNewAnimTop.top + "px", 
            "left":itemPosNewAnimLeft.left + "px",
            "height": activeWidthNewAnimHeight + "px",
            "width": activeWidthNewAnimWidth + "px"
        });
    });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){ test(); });
});
$(window).on('resize', function(){
    setTimeout(function(){ test(); }, 500);
});
$(".navbar-toggler").click(function(){
    $(".navbar-collapse").slideToggle(300);
    setTimeout(function(){ test(); });
});



// --------------add active class-on another-page move----------
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    // Get current path and find target link
    var path = window.location.pathname.split("/").pop();

    // Account for home page with empty path
    if ( path == '' ) {
        path = 'index.html';
    }

    var target = $('#navbarSupportedContent ul li a[href="'+path+'"]');
    
    // Add active class to target link
    target.parent().addClass('active');
});




// Add active class on another page linked
// ==========================================
// $(window).on('load',function () {
//     var current = location.pathname;
//     console.log(current);
//     $('#navbarSupportedContent ul li a').each(function(){
//         var $this = $(this);
//         // if the current path is like this link, make it active
//         if($this.attr('href').indexOf(current) !== -1){
//             $this.parent().addClass('active');
//             $this.parents('.menu-submenu').addClass('show-dropdown');
//             $this.parents('.menu-submenu').parent().addClass('active');
//         }else{
//             $this.parent().removeClass('active');
//         }
//     })
// });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-custom navbar-mainbg">
    <a class="navbar-brand navbar-logo" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false"
      aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <i class="fas fa-bars text-white"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <div class="hori-selector">
          <div class="left"></div>
          <div class="right"></div>
        </div>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(adress-book.html);"><i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i>Dashboard</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="far fa-address-book"></i>Address Book</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="far fa-clone"></i>Components</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i>Calendar</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="far fa-chart-bar"></i>Charts</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="far fa-copy"></i>Documents</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

please..............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far, as I know, in javascript, there is no way to implement html document in your page, by changing the url. It may be done on the server side, but not on front-end.

If you want to display some content based on selected tab, just set "display: block" for selected content when you pressed some tab, and set "display: none" for others.

Comment: "If you want to display some content based on selected tab, just set "display: block" for selected content when you pressed some tab, and set "display: none" for others." how can it be done using java script?